# View and interact a 3d model in iPad application

Tags: ipad, xcode4, 3d-model

i wanna ask you about how to display a 3d model exported from blender/3d max/maya and interact with it on iPad app.

I wanna load a 3d human head into my `UISplitViewController` Detail View

[image]

the head will be rotated, and when i came over the noise for example, i wanna it highlighted,and when i click it, it take me to another `UIViewController`.

I've searched about it and i came up with using HTML5, but it's hard to use.

I've came up with using Cocos3d and other engines, but how i can use it in a normal app, not a game.

can you please give me a hint about where i should start ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an engine called "isgl3d engine" that have a powerful capabilities and easy to use in your iPhone/iPad app.

Comment: I am using NinevehGL, but I am curious to know how your experience was with iSGL3D. Do you have any problems converting to POD files?